# Generating name based on ID and current year using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers, database-trigger

I am trying to generate value for the `ProjektNummer` (Name) column based on the value of the `ID` (primary key column.

So for example, when `ID` is `142`, then the `ProjektNummer` should be `19142`. `19` indicating the current year and `142` is the value of its `ID`.

Now, when the year changes, the id part in the value of the project name column needs to be restarted from zero while the actual ID should follow the identity and be incremented by 1 as usual.

So if the last record in the Year 2019 has ID=164, the first record in the year 2020 should be:

```
ID: 165 ProjektNummer: 20001
```

.. and the second record in year 2020 would be:

```
ID: 166 ProjektNummer: 20002
```

One way to achieve this is by creating a new view say 'vMaxLastId' and storing the max value of 'ID' for its corresponding year. This record will be used as a reference in another trigger.

So, if the first record in the year 2020 has ID: 165 Another trigger will subtract the value (164) for year 2019 (which is stored in the view), from the value of 'ID' after inserting a new record in 'table1' using the second trigger. (this should be done before inserting tho)

```
165-164=1
166-164=2
167-164=3
....
```

When the year will change from 2019 to 2020 the max id and year in 2020 will be added as a new record in the view. I have implemented this but there are multiple problems associated with this approach.

Kindly suggest me any possible way to solve this problem. I am willing to make any kind of change to the DB, query or trigger or the whole concept.

Comment: You might have a separate table with the maximum id per  year and keep this up-to-date with triggers.  This might not be an effective solution if you have high volumes of inserts.

Answer (score 0):

The first thought that crossed my mind would be to create a [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) object to generate the `ID` portion of the value. Since there are no fancy rules around the numbering, just this should do.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.ProjektID;
```

That will give you a `bigint`. To consume it, `CONCAT` that to the current year, and put your padding zeros onto the sequence value. You could set this as the default value for the column.

```
CONCAT( YEAR( GETDATE() ) % 100 , RIGHT( CONCAT('000', NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.ProjektID), 3))
```

Then schedule a job to run at midnight on the first of the year to restart the sequence.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.ProjektID
  RESTART;
```

I think that would cover your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have implemented it. Is there a way to test this job?

Answer (score 0):

The most pragmatic solution I could think of is the use of a `INSTEAD OF` trigger on that specific main table.

My test table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTestProject
(
  id            INT          IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, dateInserted  DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
, projectNumber INT          NULL
);
```

And the example trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.triMyTestProject
ON dbo.MyTestProject
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE
    @maxYear      INT
  , @maxNumber    INT
  , @startNumber  INT
  , @dateInserted DATETIME2;

  SELECT
       @dateInserted = dateInserted
  FROM Inserted;

  SET @startNumber = CAST(FORMAT(@dateInserted, 'yy') AS INT) * 1000 + 1;

  SELECT
       @maxNumber = MAX(projectNumber)
     , @maxYear   = ISNULL(MAX(YEAR(dateInserted)), YEAR(@dateInserted))
  FROM dbo.MyTestProject;

  INSERT INTO dbo.MyTestProject
    (
      dateInserted
    , projectNumber
    )
  VALUES
    (
      @dateInserted, IIF(YEAR(@dateInserted) > @maxYear OR @maxNumber IS NULL, @startNumber, @maxNumber + 1)
    );
END;
```

Add test data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTestProject (dateInserted) VALUES (SYSDATETIME());
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTestProject (dateInserted) VALUES (SYSDATETIME());
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTestProject (dateInserted) VALUES (SYSDATETIME());
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTestProject (dateInserted) VALUES ('20200102');
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTestProject (dateInserted) VALUES ('20200202');
```

Test result:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTestProject;


id          dateInserted                projectNumber
----------- --------------------------- -------------
1           2019-12-06 17:27:58.8813628 19001
2           2019-12-06 17:27:58.8833638 19002
3           2019-12-06 17:27:58.8883448 19003
4           2020-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 20001
5           2020-02-02 00:00:00.0000000 20002
```